# Use an integer field to store the selectged days with bitwise op

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm writing a form which contains all days of the week, but theses days are save in an int field $days. I'm using bitwise-op to display the selected days.

```
{% if (day.days b-and 1) == 1 %}
    {{ "sunday" |trans }}
{% endif %}
{% if (day.days b-and 2) == 2 %}
    {{ "monday" |trans }}
{% endif %}
....
```

I don't know how to do to display the checkbox array and convert it into an int and the opposite.

Here is a part of the formtype

```
    $informations = $builder->create('information', FormType::class, [
        'label'=>'Information',
        'inherit_data' => true,
        'label_attr' => ['class'=>'catlabel']])
        ->add('categoryQualityView', ChoiceType::class, [
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'viewQuality',
            'choices' => PlaceRepository::$categoriesRates,
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'selectpicker',
            ],
        ])
        ->add('categoryGastronomy', ChoiceType::class, [
            'label' => 'Gastronomy',
            'required' => true,
            'choices' => PlaceRepository::$categoriesGastronomy,
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'selectpicker',
            ],
        ])
        ->add('price', MoneyType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'label' => 'Price',
        ])
        ->add('days', IntegerType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'label' => 'Days',
        ])
        ->add('description', TextType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'label' => 'Description',
        ])
        ;
```

Comment: Do you have a FormType or something like this? If yes could you add it to your question

Comment: Part of formtype added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case you can create a custom ["Form Field Type"](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html) (and maybe if needed a custom [Data Transformer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html)) and customize also the form template as described in the docs.

For example:

```
class DaysOfWeekType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'choices' => [
                'Monday' => 1,
                'Tuesday' => 2,
                ...
            ],
        ]);
    }

    public function getParent(): string
    {
        return ChoiceType::class;
    }
}
```